# SHA-1 HMAC example

Tags: java, cryptography, sha1, hmac

I am in a security class at college and we are going over hashing algorithms right now. I have been looking all over to find a good explanation of how HMAC gets from a key and message to a hash, but I can't find one. The wiki page and every other page I have gone to are very ambiguous. They say if you have this key and this message it turns into this hash, but no explanation on how it got there. I have been working from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code trying to replicate the SHA-1 hash using java.

In Java I am using:

```
byte[] bytes;
java.security.MessageDigest d = null;
d = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
d.reset();
d.update(str.getBytes());
bytes = d.digest();
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for(byte b : bytes){
    s.append(Util.binToHex(Util.unsign(b)));
}
return s.toString();
```

Java deals with signed bits, so
Util.unsign converts it from signed to unsigned.
Util.binToHex turns the byte into hex.
I have verified those and they work just fine.
As far as I know the way that I'm doing this I have to give the function a byte[] which I always get from the string class, so whenever I do sha-1 hashing I convert the hex code into strings then get the byte array.
example: 0x65 0x73 would turn into "es".

```
Key: "key"
Message: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
BlockSize: 64
IPad: "0x36" repeated 64 times (3636363636...)
OPad: "0x5C" repeated 64 times (5C5C5C5C5C...)
```

That much I know I have right. Everything that follows is getting me.

First I convert Key to hex.
`KeyInHex = 0x6B 0x65 0x79`
Then since KeyInHex is shorter than BlockSize bytes, I don't have to hash it.
I do have to pad KeyInHex with 0x00 until it is the size of BlockSize.
`KeyInHex = 0x6B 0x65 0x79 0x00 0x00 ...`
I xOr KeyInHex with IPad.
`IKeyPad = 0x5D 0x53 0x4F 0x36 0x36 ...`
Next I append message to IKeyPad
`BeforeFirstHash = 0x5D 0x53 0x4F 0x36 ... 0x36 + 0x54 0x68 0x65 ...`
I convert my hex to a string, then get the byte array and hash it.
`BeforeFirstHash = "]SO6...6The..."`
`FirstHash = 0x0E 0xFE 0x15 0xF9 0x16 0x1A 0xB7 ...`
Next I xOr KeyInHex with OPad.
`OKeyPad = 0x37 0x39 0x25 0x5C 0x5C ...`
Append FirstHash to OKeyPad
`BeforeSecondHash = 0x37 0x39 0x25 0x5C 0x5C ... 0x5C + 0x0E 0xFE 0x15 ...`
Convert to to String, get byte array and hash
`BeforeSecondHash = "79%\\...\(Shift out)~(carriage return)..."`
`SecondHash = 0x5D 0x8C 0xF2 0x45 0x8A ...`
The correct hash is 0xDE 0x7C 0x9B 0x85 0xB8... and that is not what I got.

Can anybody help me out?

---

EDIT

---

```
main(){
    int blockSize = 64;
    String key = "key";
    String message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    StringBuilder ipad = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder opad = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder prime = new StringBuilder();
    for(byte b : key.getBytes()){
        prime.append(Util.binToHex(Util.unsign(b)));
    }
    while(prime.length() < blockSize * 2){
        prime.append("00");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < blockSize; ++i){
        opad.append("5c");
        ipad.append("36");
    }

    String iKeyPad = Util.xOr(prime.toString(), ipad.toString());
    String oKeyPad = Util.xOr(prime.toString(), opad.toString());

    String first = hash(Util.hexToString(iKeyPad) + message);
    String second = hash(Util.hexToString(oKeyPad + first));
    if(second.equals("de7c9b85b8b78aa6bc8a7a36f70a90701c9db4d9")){
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(second);
    }
}
private String hash(String str){
    try{
        byte[] bytes;
        java.security.MessageDigest d = null;
        d = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        d.reset();
        d.update(str.getBytes());
        bytes = d.digest();
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for(byte b : bytes){
            s.append(Util.binToHex(Util.unsign(b)));
        }
        return s.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
public static String xOr(String a, String b){
    a = hexToBin(a);
    b = hexToBin(b);
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i){
        if(a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i)){
            str.append("1");
        }
        else{
            str.append("0");
        }
    }
    return binToHex(str.toString());
}

public static String hexToString(String str){
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 2){
        int number = Integer.valueOf(str.substring(i, i + 2), 16);
        string.append((char)number);
    }
    return string.toString();
}
public static String binToHex(String str){
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 4){
        String temp = str.substring(i, i + 4);
        string.append(Integer.toString(Integer.valueOf(temp, 2), 16));
    }
    return string.toString();
}
public static String unsign(byte b){
    int x = b;
    if(x < 0){
        x = x * -1;
        String str = Integer.toString(x, 2);
        while(str.length() != 8){
            str = "0" + str;
        }
        str = inverse(str);
        str = addOne(str);
        return str;
    }
    else{
        String str = Integer.toString(x, 2);
        while(str.length() != 8){
            str = "0" + str;
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE

---

Thanks for the help, when I left it as byte[] it worked. I'm still not entirely sure why, but I got the correct answer. So thanks for the help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Could you share your actual code instead of the text description of what you're doing?

Comment: It looks like something's wrong with your SHA-1 hashing. Your `BeforeFirstHash` value looks correct, but your `FirstHash` is wrong. [DuckDuckGo can tell you the correct SHA-1 hash.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sha1+%5DSO6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666The+quick+brown+fox+jumped+over+the+lazy+dog&ia=answer)

Comment: First check that your SAH-1 implementation is correct.  If that fails then the HMAC will fail as well.  There are SHA-1 test vectors at [NSRL](http://www.nsrl.nist.gov/testdata/) for you to check against.

Comment: In cryptography-adjacent code `String` almost always causes trouble and `byte[]` is your friend (in older RFCs when they say "string" they usually mean "ASCII text as bytes", in a UTF world they say string far less often). You may want to try operating on bytes and only converting those bytes to hex for printing debugging info.